# Missing property exception when trying to send HTML content in the form of an email

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm rendering a view and trying to send an email. But the following error occurs:

```
Class
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message
No such property: content for class: grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder
```

The code:

```
def content=groovyPageRenderer.render view: '/email/mail', model: [username: u]

 if(mailService!=null){
    mailService.sendMail {
    to "mail@yahoo.com"
    from "f@fff.com"
    subject "rrr"

    html(content)
 }
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code sample to do the same

```
class FeedbackController {
    def mailService // <-- Injection of mail service from the 'mail' plugin

    def sendTestMsg() {
        mailService.sendMail {
            to "test@mail.test"
            subject "Some important topic"
            html g.render(template: "contactMailTemplate",
                    model: [remark: "Test one-two-three", yourname: "Testing bot", yourmail: "testbot@mail.test"])
        }
        render "success"
    }
}
```

And the `_contactMailTemplate.gsp`. Which is standard HTML, but I've replaced "<>" signs to "[]" because of StackOverflow eats them and use for formatting.

```
[%@ page contentType="text/html" %]
[html]
[head]
    [title]Welcome Aboard[/title]
    [style type="text/css"]
    body {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS"
    }
    [/style]
[/head]
[body]
[h2]Question from users![/h2]
[p]
    [strong]${yourname}[/strong] asked us from the [strong]${yourmail}[/strong] address
[/p]
[p]
    ${remark}
[/p]
[/body]
[/html]
```