# Unable to send a simple email - Beginner

Tags: grails

I am trying to send a mail from the Service class.

From the `UserCOntroller.groovy` i am calling the service method that sends email

```
maillingService.sendEmails(user)
```

`MailingService.groovy` **Service** **: Code below**

```
class MailingService {
    def sendEmails(User user) {
        // def mailService // I ALSO TRIED WITH AND WITHOUT THIS ATTRIBUTE
        mailService.sendMail {
            to "fred@g2one.com","ginger@g2one.com"
            from "john@g2one.com"
            cc "marge@g2one.com", "ed@g2one.com"
            bcc "joe@g2one.com"
            subject "Hello John"
            body 'this is some text'
         }
}
```

Error i get is:

```
No such property: mailService for class: mypro.MailingService. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: mailService for class: mypro.MailingService
```

EDIT CODE

```
def sendEmail(def u){

    MailingService m = new MailingService()
m.sendEmails(u)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `def mailService` but it needs to be a field declaration (at the class level) rather than a local variable inside the method:

```
class MailingService {
    def mailService

    def sendEmails(User user) {
        mailService.sendMail {
            to "fred@g2one.com","ginger@g2one.com"
            from "john@g2one.com"
            cc "marge@g2one.com", "ed@g2one.com"
            bcc "joe@g2one.com"
            subject "Hello John"
            body 'this is some text'
        }
    }
}
```

Also you should *not* instantiate a service class yourself in the controller, instead you should autowire it in the same way you do with the `mailService` above:

```
class SampleController {
    def mailingService

    def sendEmail(User u) {
        mailingService.sendEmails(u)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i have added it in my Post above. I get the same error. See code above. I have left a commented on it

Comment: @Illep your comment suggests that you tried `def mailService` as a local variable declaration inside the `sendEmails` method, my answer is that it needs to be a _field_ declaration (inside the class but outside the method) rather than a method-local variable.

Comment: Sorry. I tried it your way but i end up with the error message `Cannot invoke method sendMail() on null object`. HELP

Comment: @Illep and I'm assuming you have added the `mail` plugin dependency to your BuildConfig

Comment: Yes i did. Actually, the same method works in side the controller. But i want it to be in the **Service** class. I added `runtime ":mail:1.0.4"` in BuildConfig file

Comment: @Ilep can you edit the question to show your controller that's calling the `mailingService`?  As long as your service class is a real service (i.e. it lives under `grails-app/services`) and you're autowiring it into your controller correctly (i.e. with `def mailingService` - you're _not_ trying to instantiate it directly with `new MailingService()`) then it should work.

Comment: @Illep this goes right down to the fundamentals of how services work in Grails - you should never need to `new` a service class yourself in application code, just autowire it with an appropriate field declaration and let Grails take care of configuring the service for you.

Comment: @Illep What about first copy of that question you have [asked Jun 29 at 5:12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473358/missing-property-exception-when-trying-to-send-html-content-in-the-form-of-an-em/24474030)? I thought I gave you the same answer