# Sending mail No such property g

Tags: grails

I am getting this error message:

```
No such property: g for class: grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder
```

The code is:

```
mailService.sendMail {
                to "ddd@dd.com" 
                from "dd.dd@dd.com" 
                subject "Welcdome to d "
                body "jjj"
                html g.render(template: "/email/mailll",
            model: [remark: "OLAA PEOPLE!", yourname: user.firstName, yourmail: user.username])
            }
```

Comment: Where is this code?  Taglibs are available in controllers but not in services.

Comment: P.S. please do not tag Grails questions with the "groovy" tag unless they are specifically questions about Groovy as a programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `html` and `body` together, just use one or the other.  The `body` call can take `view` and `model` parameters to do the template rendering itself, you don't need to use `g.render` (and you can't, if you're in a service rather than a controller).

```
mailService.sendMail {
    to "ddd@dd.com" 
    from "dd.dd@dd.com" 
    subject "Welcdome to d "
    body(view:"/email/_mailll", model: [remark: "OLAA PEOPLE!",
                yourname: user.firstName, yourmail: user.username])
}
```

Note that the `view` parameter doesn't do the underscore transformation on template names, so you have to include the underscore yourself if the GSP you want to render includes one.

Answer (score 2):

This code is valid only if called in a `Controller` or `TagLib`. The `g`-Taglib object is not available in any other Grails artefacts, like `Service`.

If you want to render the email-body from a Service, you must use groovy's [SimpleTemplateEngine](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html)

Answer (score 1):

From your last question: You are in service and in service taglibs are not accessible so for sending templates you need `groovyPageRenderer` like [Missing property exception when trying to send HTML content in the form of an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473358/missing-property-exception-when-trying-to-send-html-content-in-the-form-of-an-em) in your question.